# Why custom renderer do not work as expected and cause strange table cells behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

Wh my custom renderer cause strange cell's behavior in handsontable? When I try to edit cell then after that cursor goes down to other cell automatically and other cells are haywire and whole editing process is crashed from that moment.

I need to colorize some cells according to the values and that's why I need to use some mechanism, I've chosen defining type in column definition like that:

```
columns: { data: "some-property", type: {renderer: colorRenderer, editor:colorRenderer}}
```

Unfortunately when I do this then some strange behavior occurs during cell edit. Please just take a look at jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6QEtF/3/
line: 191 is the problematic issue.

How can I colorize cells in other way without using renderer or what is wrong with my renderer?

Please help...

Here is my sample code, fully working is on JsFiddle (link above).

```
var COLUMN_TYPES = new Object();

// JSON fetched via Ajax from backend:
var res = getJSON();

// Create grid header names and definitions based on fetched JSON:
var column_names = [];
var column_defs = [];
for (var i=0; i<res.headers.length; i++) {
    column_names[i] = res.headers[i].name;
    column_defs[i] = {
        data: "valueDTO." + i + ".value", 
        type: {renderer: colorRenderer, editor:colorEditor}, // 1 way <--- cause a problem! 
        //type: res.headers[i].type,    // 2nd way is correct but without custom renderer which I need to colorize some cells.
        source: res.headers[i].sources, 
        readOnly: res.headers[i].readOnly, 
        strict: res.headers[i].strict
    };
    COLUMN_TYPES["valueDTO."+i+".value"] = res.headers[i].type;
}

// Create grid table:
createHandsontable(res.rows, column_names, column_defs, res.values);

function createHandsontable(row_names, column_names, column_defs, values) {
    var $container = $("#spreadsheet");
    var $parent = $container.parent();
    $container.handsontable({
      startRows: 4,
      startCols: 20,
      manualColumnResize: true,
      manualColumnMove: true,
      columnSorting: true,
      contextMenu: true,
      rowHeaders: row_names,
      colHeaders: column_names, //grid.headers,
      data: values, // data init only once at start
      columns: column_defs,
      cells: function (row, col, prop) {
          //return {type: {renderer: colorRenderer, editor: colorEditor}};
      }
    });
}

function colorRenderer (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    switch (COLUMN_TYPES[prop]) {   
        case 'text':
            Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
            Handsontable.TextCell.editor.apply(this, arguments);
            if (value != null) {
                if (value.toString().toLowerCase() === "green") {
                    $(td).css({
                        background: '#00DC00'
                    });
                }
                else if (value.toString().toLowerCase() === "amber") {
                    $(td).css({
                        background: '#FAE600'
                    });
                }
                else if (value.toString().toLowerCase() === "red") {
                    $(td).css({
                        background: 'red'
                    });
                }
            }   
            break;
        case 'autocomplete':
            Handsontable.AutocompleteCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
            Handsontable.AutocompleteCell.editor.apply(this, arguments);
            break;
        case 'checkbox':
            Handsontable.CheckboxCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
            Handsontable.CheckboxCell.editor.apply(this, arguments);
            break;
        case 'numeric':
            Handsontable.NumericCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
            Handsontable.NumericCell.editor.apply(this, arguments);
            break;
        case 'date':
            Handsontable.DateCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
            Handsontable.DateCell.editor.apply(this, arguments);
            break;
        case 'handsontable':
            Handsontable.HandsontableCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
            Handsontable.HandsontableCell.editor.apply(this, arguments);
            break;
        default:
            Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
            Handsontable.TextCell.editor.apply(this, arguments);
            break;
    }
};

function colorEditor (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    switch (COLUMN_TYPES[prop]) {   
        case 'text':
            Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
            Handsontable.TextCell.editor.apply(this, arguments);
            break;
        case 'autocomplete':
            Handsontable.AutocompleteCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
            Handsontable.AutocompleteCell.editor.apply(this, arguments);
            break;
        case 'checkbox':
            Handsontable.CheckboxCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
            Handsontable.CheckboxCell.editor.apply(this, arguments);
            break;
        case 'numeric':
            Handsontable.NumericCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
            Handsontable.NumericCell.editor.apply(this, arguments);
            break;
        case 'date':
            Handsontable.DateCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
            Handsontable.DateCell.editor.apply(this, arguments);
            break;
        case 'handsontable':
            Handsontable.HandsontableCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
            Handsontable.HandsontableCell.editor.apply(this, arguments);
            break;
        default:
            Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
            Handsontable.TextCell.editor.apply(this, arguments);
            break;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try upgrading to the [latest version](http://handsontable.com/):

```
http://handsontable.com/
```

And have a look at [conditional formatting](http://handsontable.com/demo/conditional.html)